# How to retrieve text from JSON

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve a token from a JSON response. I've successfully managed to get a response, but I don't know how to retrieve the token.

Here's my code

```
private void TmdbAuth() {

    final String TokenUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/token/new?api_key=<<api key goes here>>";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            TokenUrl,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        Log.i("jjj", response.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

and the response of this json

```
{"success":true,"expires_at":"2019-04-01 10:49:44 UTC","request_token":"request token goes here"}
```

How do I retrieve only the `request_token`

Comment: response.getString("request_token);

Comment: check my answer @tony.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this @tony

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject(response); //obtained response from the server.
String request_token = object.getString("request_token");
Log.e("request_token",request_token); //Just for checking in the logcat.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access token String this way

```
String token = response.optString("request_token");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
try{
     Log.i("jjj", response.toString());
     String requestToken = response.getString("request_token");
   }
catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```